# recaptcha responded, but Ajax not getting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm having some trouble with my code. It seems that when I get the reCAPTCHA response it loads when I alert the variable, but AJAX isn't wanting to get it.

```
 var url="";
    if (DEPOSIT) {
        url = "/get_inv?" + opts;
    } else {
        var g = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        url = "/get_bank_safe?g-recaptcha-response=" + g;
    }
    alert(url);
    $.ajax({
        "url": url,
        success: function(data) {
            try {
                alert(data);
                data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Yes I've gotten a valid response from the URL variable itself, but when announcing the AJAX variable 'data', nothing is persevered. Therefore JSON cannot parse 'data'.

It even states that "url" : url.

So I'm not sure how to go about this. If there is any solution please alert me of so.

Thanks! ~LTn | mrgreen33gamer

Comment: `data` is a local variable in this case. You need to store the value of parsed data into another global variable for later use, like that `url` can.

Comment: you need to declare the data variable. eg. var data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: @KarthikMR how would that help anything?

Comment: `getResponse()` is not likely synchronous ... where does that method come from?

Comment: @charlietfl - have look at his problem, data is not preserved, but he is getting the response. And both the names are data.

Comment: @KarthikMR declaring data as local variable again inside success handler won't help

Comment: again? he has not declared it.  And both the names are data

Comment: @KarthikMR you are missing the point...if it is something that needs to be stored creating a local variable inside `success` is useless... `var` needs to be outside the ajax and would need different variable name

Comment: but where is he accessing the data variable outside? @juan pls post it. can you also post the alert(data) ?

Comment: @KarthikMR I get this when announcing the Variable: [URL variable](http://i.imgur.com/KaScXTO.png) but when announcing alert(data) NOTHING is presented.